# Beamer with Tikzpicture. How to change scale of picture and distance between lines of nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I am a beginner in LaTeX, trying to convert a presentation in `beamer`. I am experiencing difficulties with the `scale` option that does  not seem to work, and I cound not find a way to reduce slightly the space between text lines in the nodes of the tikz picture

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames, smaller]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 
\mode<presentation> {
 \usetheme{Warsaw}
% \usetheme{default}
}

\title{\textcolor{white}{Test slide}} %Normal title
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\section{Second section}
\section{Third section}
\section{Fourth section}
\section{Sixth section}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Extremely long title for this particular slide, further elongated to serve as example}
\alert {Include all value -added and non value-added steps (Process steps, inspection/test, rework, scrap, delay\dots)}\\
\textbf{Manufacturing}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, %does not seem to work
font=\footnotesize,
     start chain,
     node distance=2mm,
     mynode/.style={draw, fill= cyan!20, text width=1.5cm, text badly centered, inner sep=0.5 ex, rounded corners= 0.2 ex,join=by #1},
     mynode/.default=->
]
\node [mynode,on chain] {Move\\ Move \\ material\\from \\ storage};
\node [mynode,on chain] {Wait\\ Store \\ in \\staging\\ area};
\node [mynode,on chain] {Set-up\\ Set up \\ \& \\ adjust die, reeler\dots};
\node [mynode,on chain] {Stamp \\four-out die,\\ six\\ stations\\ in die\\};
\node [mynode,on chain] {Move\\ Move\\ to\\ inspection,\\ wait};
\node [mynode,on chain] {Inventory\\ Return to stores to wait further processing};
\end{tikzpicture}
\textbf{\textcolor{green}{Transactional (Non-Manufacturing)}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, font=\footnotesize,
     start chain,
     node distance=2mm,
     mynode/.style={draw, fill= cyan!20, text width=2.5cm, text badly centered, inner sep=0.5 ex, rounded corners= 0.2 ex,join=by #1},
     mynode/.default=->
]
\node [mynode,on chain] {Answer phone Greet customer  Determine parts needed\\ Identify need date\\ Identify price  Identify shipping address \& method};
\node [mynode,on chain] {Internal information\\ Get internal P/N\\ Determine terms\\ Identify\\ leadtime \\Complete\\ order\\ worksheet};
\node [mynode,on chain] {Order entry\\Input\\ information\\Print order confirmation\\ Determinin ship date \\ review order};
\node [mynode,on chain] {File / Queue \\ File for\\ end-of-day\\ processing\\ queue for\\batch download 10:00 est. next work day};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `scale`, consider using `transform shape` as well, so that the transformation (here: scaling) is applied, via option to node or to the whole picture. For example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape, ...
```

Comment: Thanks. This did it. In the meanwhile, I have also found very handy the frame option \begin{frame}[shrink=5].