# Scaling tikz mindmaps within a beamer frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, scaling, mindmaps

I recently discovered tikz and I fell in love with it! However, I am having some annoying issues when I try to include a tikz mindmap in beamer. Problem is that I can't manage to have the mindmap scaled to the beamer slide size. Below is my code, see attached image for my output. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[8pt,T]{beamer}  
\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees, backgrounds}

\useoutertheme{tree}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{alertblock body}{fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default]
\usecolortheme[named=orange]{structure}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\title{Bla bla}
\author{George Azzari}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{figure}[h]
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CANOPY STRUCTURE
  \path[mindmap,concept color=green!50!black, text=white]

    node[concept](struct) at (0,0){Canopy Structure}
            child[grow = -45, concept color = orange]{
            node[concept](light){Light Interception}
                    [clockwise from = 20]
                    child{node[concept](alb) {Shortwave albedo}}
                    child{node[concept](lw){Longwave Emissivity}}
                    child{node[concept](shade){Shading}}
                    }
        %----------------------------------------------------------
            child[grow = 45, concept color = green!50!yellow!70!black]{
                node[concept](func){Ecosystem Function}
                    [counterclockwise from = -20]
                    child{node[concept](massflu) {Mass Fluxes}}
                    child{node[concept](biom) {Biomass}}
                    child{node[concept](prod){Production}}
                    child{node[concept](comp) {Competition}
                        child{}}
                    }
        %----------------------------------------------------------
            child[grow = 0, concept color = blue!60!white]{
                node[concept](rough) at (0.5,0){Turbolence}
                    child[grow = 20]{node[concept](lh){Latent Heat}}
                    child[grow = -20]{node[concept](sh){Sensible Heat}}};
        %----------------------------------------------------------

%%%%%%%%%%%% ATMOSPHERE
  \path[mindmap,concept color=blue!80!white!60!green, text=white]
    node[concept](atmos) at (12,4){Atmospheric Exchanges};

%%%%%%%%%%%% ENERGY
  \path[mindmap,concept color=red!50!black, text=white]
    node[concept](energy) at (12,-4){Surface Energy};

%%%%%%%%%%%%% MAKING SECONDARY CONNECTIONS 
  \newcommand{\conngreentoorange}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (green!50!yellow!70!black) to (orange)]}
  \newcommand{\connredtoorange}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!50!black) to (orange)]}
  \newcommand{\connredtoblu}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!50!black) to (blue!60!white)]}
  \newcommand{\connazuretoblu}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!80!white!60!green) to (blue!60!white)]}
  \newcommand{\connazuretogreen}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!80!white!60!green) to (green!50!yellow!70!black)]}
  \newcommand{\connazuretored}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!80!white!60!green) to (red!50!black)]}
  \newcommand{\connblutogreen}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!60!white) to (green!50!yellow!70!black)]}
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    %\draw [circle connection bar ]
      \path (func)  \conngreentoorange (light);
      \path (energy)\connredtoorange (alb);      
      \path (energy)\connredtoorange (lw);
      \path (energy)\connredtoblu (sh);
      \path (energy)\connredtoblu (lh);
      \path (atmos) \connazuretoblu (lh);
      \path (atmos) \connazuretoblu (sh);
      \path (atmos) \connazuretored (energy);
      \path (atmos) \connazuretogreen (massflu);
      \path (lh) \connblutogreen (massflu);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Along this site it is possible to find a lot of questions and answers related to scaling `tikzpicture`s. Here I add some references:

- [How to scale a tikzpicture to \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-to-textwidth)
- [How to scale a tikzpicture including texts?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26846/how-to-scale-a-tikzpicture-including-texts)
- [Correctly scaling a tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/correctly-scaling-a-tikzpicture)

In particular:

- [Beamer with Tikzpicture. How to change scale of picture and distance between lines of nodes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67006/beamer-with-tikzpicture-how-to-change-scale-of-picture-and-distance-between-lin) is related to `tikzpicture`s in Beamer

and

- [How to decrease the size of single node in mindmap?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58237/how-to-decrease-the-size-of-single-node-in-mindmap) to adapt `mindmap` nodes size, which ultimately is what you need to fit the slide.

Starting from you example, it was sufficient to properly declare the distances of the various mindmap's levels by means of:

```
\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=90,level distance = 27mm}}
\tikzset{level 2 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=45,level distance = 17mm}}
\tikzset{every node/.append style={scale=0.6}}
```

and to change the position of the concepts `Atmospheric Exchanges` and `Surface Energy`: you gave them by hand, but they actually were placed too much far.

Notice also that I removed yours

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
```

not really needed.

The complete code:

```
\documentclass[8pt,T]{beamer}  
\usepackage{comment} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees, backgrounds}

\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=90,level distance = 27mm}}
\tikzset{level 2 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=45,level distance = 17mm}}
\tikzset{every node/.append style={scale=0.6}}    

\useoutertheme{tree}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{alertblock body}{fg=black}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default]
\usecolortheme[named=orange]{structure}
\usetheme{Antibes}

\title{Bla bla}
\author{George Azzari}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% CANOPY STRUCTURE
  \path[mindmap,concept color=green!50!black, text=white]

    node[concept](struct) at (0,0){Canopy Structure}
            child[grow = -45, concept color = orange]{
            node[concept](light){Light Interception}
                    [clockwise from = 20]
                    child{node[concept](alb) {Shortwave albedo}}
                    child{node[concept](lw){Longwave Emissivity}}
                    child{node[concept](shade){Shading}}
                    }
        %----------------------------------------------------------
            child[grow = 45, concept color = green!50!yellow!70!black]{
                node[concept](func){Ecosystem Function}
                    [counterclockwise from = -20]
                    child{node[concept](massflu) {Mass Fluxes}}
                    child{node[concept](biom) {Biomass}}
                    child{node[concept](prod){Production}}
                    child{node[concept](comp) {Competition}}
                    }
        %----------------------------------------------------------
            child[grow = 0, concept color = blue!60!white]{
                node[concept](rough) at (0.5,0){Turbolence}
                    child[grow = 20]{node[concept](lh){Latent Heat}}
                    child[grow = -20]{node[concept](sh){Sensible Heat}}};
        %----------------------------------------------------------

%%%%%%%%%%%% ATMOSPHERE
  \path[mindmap,concept color=blue!80!white!60!green, text=white]
    node[concept](atmos) at (8,2){Atmospheric Exchanges};

%%%%%%%%%%%% ENERGY
  \path[mindmap,concept color=red!50!black, text=white]
    node[concept](energy) at (8,-2){Surface Energy};

%%%%%%%%%%%%% MAKING SECONDARY CONNECTIONS 
  \newcommand{\conngreentoorange}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (green!50!yellow!70!black) to (orange)]}
  \newcommand{\connredtoorange}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!50!black) to (orange)]}
  \newcommand{\connredtoblu}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (red!50!black) to (blue!60!white)]}
  \newcommand{\connazuretoblu}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!80!white!60!green) to (blue!60!white)]}
  \newcommand{\connazuretogreen}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!80!white!60!green) to (green!50!yellow!70!black)]}
  \newcommand{\connazuretored}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!80!white!60!green) to (red!50!black)]}
  \newcommand{\connblutogreen}{to[circle connection bar switch color=from (blue!60!white) to (green!50!yellow!70!black)]}
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    %\draw [circle connection bar ]
      \path (func)  \conngreentoorange (light);
      \path (energy)\connredtoorange (alb);      
      \path (energy)\connredtoorange (lw);
      \path (energy)\connredtoblu (sh);
      \path (energy)\connredtoblu (lh);
      \path (atmos) \connazuretoblu (lh);
      \path (atmos) \connazuretoblu (sh);
      \path (atmos) \connazuretored (energy);
      \path (atmos) \connazuretogreen (massflu);
      \path (lh) \connblutogreen (massflu);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Cool, grazie Claudio! It looks great now.