# Displaying a probability tree on beamer

Tags: beamer, formatting

I would like to modify the code here :

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/scenario-tree/

in order to make it fit on beamer page.
The code works on a regular article page, but the tree is way too large for a beamer slide.. what shoud I change in the code in order to have the tree on a single slide ?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Slightly related to your problem, [Scaling tikz mindmaps within a beamer frame](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78202/13304), contains useful references to scale a TikZ picture.

Comment: If you don't mind to 'scale' it, you can use `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{all tikz code}`. Another option would be to produce a pdf file (with `standalone` class) and include with `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{your figure}`.

Comment: @Ignasi fancy making an answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

You have two easy solutions, if you don't mind to `scale` the original tree.

First: Use [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/packages/standalone) class to produces a cropped tree which will be included in your beamer presentation with `\includegraphics` command.

Change `minimal` class with `standalone` and pdflatex it. You don't need to change anything else.

```
% Scenario tree
% Author: Rasmus Pank Roulund
% \documentclass{minimal}
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\A}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\B}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{B}}\xspace}
\newcommand\pa[1]{\ensuremath{\left(#1\right)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    grow=right,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm,level distance=5.2cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm, level distance=6.7cm},
    edge from parent/.style={very thick,draw=blue!40!black!60,
        shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)},
    kant/.style={text width=2cm, text centered, sloped},
    every node/.style={text ragged, inner sep=2mm},
    punkt/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, shade, top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!20, draw=blue!40!black!60, very
    thick }
    ]

\node[punkt, text width=5.5em] {Country~\B}
    %Lower part lv1
    child {
        node[punkt] [rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
         text ragged] {
            \textbf{Scenario  1}
                  \nodepart{second}
            $\text{Country \B}\colon    s\bar{Q}$
                  \nodepart{third}
            $\text{Country \A}\colon\pa{1-s}\bar{Q}$
        }
        edge from parent
            node[kant, below, pos=.6] {Unchanged parity}
    }
    %Upper part, lv1
    child {
        node[punkt, text width=6em] {Country~\A}
        %child 1
        child {
            node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split,
            rectangle split parts=3] {
                \textbf{Scenario  2}
                \nodepart{second}
                $\text{Country \B}\colon s\bar{Q}+2\alpha\Delta E -sc$
                \nodepart{third}
                $\text{Country \A}\colon\pa{1-s}\bar{Q}-\alpha\Delta E -
                \pa{1-s}c$
            }
            edge from parent
                node[below, kant,  pos=.6] {Unchanged parity}
        }
        %child 2
        child {
            node [punkt, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3]{
                \textbf{Scenario 3}
                \nodepart{second}
                $\text{Country \B}\colon s\bar{Q}-2sc$
                \nodepart{third}
                $\text{Country \A}\colon\pa{1-s}\bar{Q}-2\pa{1-s}c$
            }
            edge from parent
                node[kant, above] {Devalues}}
            edge from parent{
                node[kant, above] {Devalues}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now, include it in your presentation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Probability tree}

{\par\centering
% 106998 is the name I've used for probability tree figure.
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{106998}
\par}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Second: Include `Tikz` code in your beamer presentation but resize it with `\resizebox` command:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\A}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\B}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{B}}\xspace}
\newcommand\pa[1]{\ensuremath{\left(#1\right)}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Probability tree}

{\par\centering\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    grow=right,
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm,level distance=5.2cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm, level distance=6.7cm},
    edge from parent/.style={very thick,draw=blue!40!black!60,
        shorten >=5pt, shorten <=5pt},
    edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.east) -- (\tikzchildnode.west)},
    kant/.style={text width=2cm, text centered, sloped},
    every node/.style={text ragged, inner sep=2mm},
    punkt/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, shade, top color=white,
    bottom color=blue!50!black!20, draw=blue!40!black!60, very
    thick }
    ]

\node[punkt, text width=5.5em] {Country~\B}
    %Lower part lv1
    child {
        node[punkt] [rectangle split, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
         text ragged] {
            \textbf{Scenario  1}
                  \nodepart{second}
            $\text{Country \B}\colon    s\bar{Q}$
                  \nodepart{third}
            $\text{Country \A}\colon\pa{1-s}\bar{Q}$
        }
        edge from parent
            node[kant, below, pos=.6] {Unchanged parity}
    }
    %Upper part, lv1
    child {
        node[punkt, text width=6em] {Country~\A}
        %child 1
        child {
            node [punkt,rectangle split, rectangle split,
            rectangle split parts=3] {
                \textbf{Scenario  2}
                \nodepart{second}
                $\text{Country \B}\colon s\bar{Q}+2\alpha\Delta E -sc$
                \nodepart{third}
                $\text{Country \A}\colon\pa{1-s}\bar{Q}-\alpha\Delta E -
                \pa{1-s}c$
            }
            edge from parent
                node[below, kant,  pos=.6] {Unchanged parity}
        }
        %child 2
        child {
            node [punkt, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3]{
                \textbf{Scenario 3}
                \nodepart{second}
                $\text{Country \B}\colon s\bar{Q}-2sc$
                \nodepart{third}
                $\text{Country \A}\colon\pa{1-s}\bar{Q}-2\pa{1-s}c$
            }
            edge from parent
                node[kant, above] {Devalues}}
            edge from parent{
                node[kant, above] {Devalues}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}}
\par}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A third option would be to change the tree to fit in beamer slides, but this is not so easy. Some ideas to explore: make it grow down, change font size, ...