# how to make mindmap fit on frame?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, mindmaps

I'm in the process of creating a Beamer presentation using some tikz concepts, how do I make a mindmap fit to the slide?  My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[T]{beamer}

\definecolor{links}{HTML}{2A1B81}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=red}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usepackage[graphics,tightpage]{preview}

\setbeamertemplate{button}{\tikz
\node[
inner xsep=10pt,
draw=structure!80,
fill=structure!50,
rounded corners=4pt]  {\Large\insertbuttontext};}


\title{Presentation Template}
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=yellow}
\author{asdfasdfa}
\setbeamercolor{date}{fg=yellow}
\date\today



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section*{Outline}


\begin{frame}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\frametitle{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols} 
\end{frame}

\section{Timeline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ Timeline}
\centering

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[mindmap,concept color=blue, text=white, transform shape]
node[concept]{bicycle}
    child[grow=0, concept color=red]{node[concept]{road bicycle}
        child[grow=30]{node[concept]{time trial bicycle}}
        child[grow=30]{node[concept]{road racing bicycle}}}
    child[grow=60, concept color=black]{node[concept]{mountain bicycle}}    
    child[grow=120, concept color=orange]{node[concept]{tandem bicycle}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: One way would be to simply scale the entire `tikzpicture`. So something like `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]`.

Comment: From the PGF manual: “Mindmaps with `small mindmap` will also fit onto a standard frame of the `beamer` package.” You do need to change the direction of the time trial and road racing bicycle nodes to `0` and `60` respectively.

Comment: Perhaps duplicate: [Scaling tikz mindmaps within a beamer frame](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78202/13304).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another option would be to use `\resizebox`:

```
\documentclass[T]{beamer}

\definecolor{links}{HTML}{2A1B81}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=red}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usepackage[graphics,tightpage]{preview}

\setbeamertemplate{button}{\tikz
\node[
inner xsep=10pt,
draw=structure!80,
fill=structure!50,
rounded corners=4pt]  {\Large\insertbuttontext};}


\title{Presentation Template}
\setbeamercolor{author}{fg=yellow}
\author{asdfasdfa}
\setbeamercolor{date}{fg=yellow}
\date\today



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section*{Outline}


\begin{frame}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\frametitle{Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{multicols} 
\end{frame}

\section{Timeline}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{ Timeline}
\centering

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
            \path[mindmap,concept color=blue, text=white, transform shape]
            node[concept,scale=0.8]{bicycle}
            child[grow=0, concept color=red]{node[concept]{road bicycle}
                child[grow=30]{node[concept]{time trial bicycle}}
                child[grow=90]{node[concept]{road racing bicycle}}}
            child[grow=60, concept color=black]{node[concept]{mountain bicycle}}    
            child[grow=120, concept color=orange]{node[concept]{tandem bicycle}};
        \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @GonzaloMedina how would I then make those nodes links within the presentation?

Comment: @user28552 You can use the `\hypertarget`, `\hyperlink` mechanism to build links to other parts of the presentation, or `\href` to make them links to outer destinations. If you need some additional guidance, perhaps this deserves a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You can change `scale=<whatever you like>` for a few of the `nodes`- also wrapping it in a `\makebox[\textwidth]` helps a little.

[image: screenshot]

You can also change the `level distance` if you like- it's a fairly manual process, but that's ok for a presentation, as they are very different from regular documents.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: { overwrite: on}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Frankfurt}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{structuresmallcapsserif}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \makebox[\textwidth][c]{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \path[mindmap,concept color=blue, text=white, transform shape]
            node[concept,scale=0.8]{bicycle}
            child[grow=0, concept color=red]{node[concept]{road bicycle}
                child[grow=30]{node[concept]{time trial bicycle}}
                child[grow=90]{node[concept]{road racing bicycle}}}
            child[grow=60, concept color=black]{node[concept]{mountain bicycle}}    
            child[grow=120, concept color=orange]{node[concept]{tandem bicycle}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```