# Why is my resized box indented despite \noindent?

Tags: tikz-pgf, indentation, resize

I'm not able to avoid indentation of my tikzpicture inside a resized box.

I've put `\noindent` everywhere but the figure is still indented.

Maybe it's a stupid mistake but I can't fix it.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=3cm,marginparwidth=70pt}

\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,format=hang,indention=0cm]{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\noindent\begin{figure}[!t]
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\tikzset{root concept/.append style={font=\huge}}
\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={sibling angle=120, font=\small, minimum size=3cm, level distance=140pt}}
\tikzset{level 2 concept/.append style={sibling angle=60, font=\scriptsize, minimum size=2cm, level distance=100pt}}
\tikzset{level 3 concept/.append style={sibling angle=60, font=\tiny, minimum size=1.3cm, level distance=70pt}}
\tikzset{concept/.append style={fill={none}, text width=}}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[mindmap, concept color=gray!30, text=black]%
    node [concept] {\textbf{Quack}}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child { node [concept] {\makecell*{\textbf{Ducks}\\ \textbf{and ducks}}}
            [clockwise from=60]
            child { node  [concept] {\makecell*{Papere\\ Little ducks}}
                [clockwise from=90]
                child { node [concept] {Paperine}}
                child { node [concept] {Ducks}}
                }
            child { node [concept] {\makecell*{Papere\\ Funny ducks}}
               [clockwise from=30]
                child { node  [concept] {Paperine}}
                child { node [concept] {Ducks}}
                }
            child { node  [concept] {\makecell*{Papere\\ Pretty ducks}}
               [clockwise from=-30]
                child { node [concept] {Paperine}}
                child { node  [concept] {Ducks}}
              }
            }
  child { node [concept] {\makecell*{\textbf{Mallards}\\ \textbf{and mallards}}}}
  child { node [concept] {\makecell{\textbf{Geese}\\ \textbf{and geese}}}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\caption{\label{fig:test}Test figure.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sporadic spaces: the space after each `\tikzset` counts, also the one after `\end{tikzpicture}` counts in the width `\resizebox` ends up using. I'd rather recommed learning to scale the image directly than using `\resizebox`

Comment: None of your `\noindent` command does something sensible; the first one is actually wrong, as it produces a one line (otherwise empty) paragraph.

Comment: @daleif Thank you! It's sufficient to put a `%` at the end of the `\tikzset` lines and all works. I knew that it was a stupid error! I tried to scale the picture without `\resizebox` but I wasn't able to do that!

Comment: @egreg I've put `\noindent` everywhere just to try to find the solution!

Comment: @CarLaTeX, your missing the one after `\end{tikzpicture}`, you'll probably not notice until use add the stuff I mention in the comment to Davids answer

Comment: @daleif OK, thank you for your clarification!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, paragraph indentation is 0pt inside a float so the `\noindent` inside are doing nothing, the `\noindent` before the `\begin{figure}` is completely wrong and will force the creation of a "white" paragraph that looks like vertical space.

The horizontal shift was not due to indentation but to extra space characters added after each of the `\tikzset` (and there was an additional space at the end of the `\resizebox`).

Note I left the option as `[!t]` but this is very restrictive as it does not allow the float to be placed on a float page, so  makes it harder for latex to find a good place. It is almost always better to include `p` or simply not have the option.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=3cm,marginparwidth=70pt}

\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,format=hang,indention=0cm]{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

%\noindent
\begin{figure}[!t]
%\noindent
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\tikzset{root concept/.append style={font=\huge}}%
\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={sibling angle=120, font=\small, minimum size=3cm, level distance=140pt}}%
\tikzset{level 2 concept/.append style={sibling angle=60, font=\scriptsize, minimum size=2cm, level distance=100pt}}%
\tikzset{level 3 concept/.append style={sibling angle=60, font=\tiny, minimum size=1.3cm, level distance=70pt}}%
\tikzset{concept/.append style={fill={none}, text width=}}%
%\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[mindmap, concept color=gray!30, text=black]%
    node [concept] {\textbf{Quack}}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child { node [concept] {\makecell*{\textbf{Ducks}\\ \textbf{and ducks}}}
            [clockwise from=60]
            child { node  [concept] {\makecell*{Papere\\ Little ducks}}
                [clockwise from=90]
                child { node [concept] {Paperine}}
                child { node [concept] {Ducks}}
                }
            child { node [concept] {\makecell*{Papere\\ Funny ducks}}
               [clockwise from=30]
                child { node  [concept] {Paperine}}
                child { node [concept] {Ducks}}
                }
            child { node  [concept] {\makecell*{Papere\\ Pretty ducks}}
               [clockwise from=-30]
                child { node [concept] {Paperine}}
                child { node  [concept] {Ducks}}
              }
            }
  child { node [concept] {\makecell*{\textbf{Mallards}\\ \textbf{and mallards}}}}
  child { node [concept] {\makecell{\textbf{Geese}\\ \textbf{and geese}}}}
;
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\caption{\label{fig:test}Test figure.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You missed the one after `\end{tikzpicture}`, illustrated using `showframe` package and inserting `\draw [blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);` into the image

Comment: @daleif fixed thanks (sorry hadn't noticed your comment under the question before making an answer:-)

Comment: I put `\noindent`s everywhere just to try to find the solution, I imagined that some of them were wrong, thank you!

Comment: @daleif I'll wait a couple of days before accepting (the very accurate) David's answer. I was thinking (if you have time and will) you could post your own answer, showing how to highlight the error through `showframe` as you said in the comment and how to scale the image directly with tikz, avoiding `\resizebox`, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 3):

This is just a supplement to Davids answer showing how to visualize the issue.

See the two lines marked by `% <--`, `showframe` visually shows the size of the text block, that is where the text width is.

The `\draw [blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current
bounding box.north east);` draws a blue box around the image showing the borders of the image. In our case it shows that the problematic spaces are outside the box, and thus most likely to come from sporadic spaces.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{showframe} % <-- added

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3.5cm,lmargin=4cm,rmargin=3cm,marginparwidth=70pt}

\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,format=hang,indention=0cm]{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,trees}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\noindent\begin{figure}[!t]
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\tikzset{root concept/.append style={font=\huge}}
\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={sibling angle=120, font=\small, minimum size=3cm, level distance=140pt}}
\tikzset{level 2 concept/.append style={sibling angle=60, font=\scriptsize, minimum size=2cm, level distance=100pt}}
\tikzset{level 3 concept/.append style={sibling angle=60, font=\tiny, minimum size=1.3cm, level distance=70pt}}
\tikzset{concept/.append style={fill={none}, text width=}}
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[mindmap, concept color=gray!30, text=black]%
    node [concept] {\textbf{Quack}}
    [clockwise from=0]
    child { node [concept] {\makecell*{\textbf{Ducks}\\ \textbf{and ducks}}}
            [clockwise from=60]
            child { node  [concept] {\makecell*{Papere\\ Little ducks}}
                [clockwise from=90]
                child { node [concept] {Paperine}}
                child { node [concept] {Ducks}}
                }
            child { node [concept] {\makecell*{Papere\\ Funny ducks}}
               [clockwise from=30]
                child { node  [concept] {Paperine}}
                child { node [concept] {Ducks}}
                }
            child { node  [concept] {\makecell*{Papere\\ Pretty ducks}}
               [clockwise from=-30]
                child { node [concept] {Paperine}}
                child { node  [concept] {Ducks}}
              }
            }
  child { node [concept] {\makecell*{\textbf{Mallards}\\ \textbf{and mallards}}}}
  child { node [concept] {\makecell{\textbf{Geese}\\ \textbf{and geese}}}}
;
\draw [blue] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current
bounding box.north east); % <-- added
\end{tikzpicture}
}%
\caption{\label{fig:test}Test figure.}
\end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: I wasn't aware of the `showframe` package. Very useful!

Comment: Thank you very much! As you see, someone else found it useful! As for scaling, unfortunately if I use `\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]` or `\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8, x=8mm,y=8mm]` the links between the nodes are too short, while if I use`\centering\begin{tikzpicture}[x=8mm,y=8mm]` (or any other value) the image is pagewidth. Maybe I have to work also on node size...

Comment: @CarLaTeX that is very strange, mind maps ignore the `x=,y=` completely. Perhaps they should be scaled in some other manner. I'll remove the comment in the text

Comment: @CarLaTeX perhaps some of this can be used: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78204/3929

Comment: @daleif Just for info: using the link you suggested to me, I've found the option for scaling mind maps: `transform shape`. For example `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.09, transform shape]`.